# How to update label control on the page using QueryStringParameter value?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, querystringparameter

I am using the QueryStringParameter to pass a parameter in the SELECT statement to display only the necessary data on the page from SQL Server.

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="doc_family" QueryStringField="doc_family" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

I was wondering what if I could take advantage of the QueryStringParameter and write some ***IF statements*** to add custom headings as per data fetched on the page instead of one generic one. As an example:

1. If (doc_family = CR) then display "Clean Room" on the page
2. If (doc_family = QA) then display "Quality Assurance" on the page
3. If (doc_family = TP) then display "Test Protocol" on the page
4. Else "Page name is not available"

Here is the code snipped for the ASP label control wrapped in H1 tag:

```
<h1 style="color:Black;">
    <asp:Label ID="DocumentNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Hello World" />
</h1>
```

My project is written in C# and the QueryStringParameter is used in this format in the URL **~/ProceduresForms.aspx?doc_family=CR**.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: some code snippets where you want to do this would be needed!

Comment: @Muthu: Thanks for the feedback. I added the code snipped and also provided some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Page_Load:

```
if(Request.QueryString["doc_family"] == "CR") DocumentNameLabel.Text = "CleanRoom";
```

You should be able to take it from there?